# router.back(), not going to previous page, but rather to first Tab in Expo Tab navigator

Tags: react-native, expo

In my `_layout.tsx`, I have a Tab navigator with all my different routes declared. Sometimes I want to redirect to a form, by using `router.push("foo")`, and then on submission, I call `router.back()`.
Instead of redirecting me to the site that I was on before, it goes to the first tab in the Tab bar.

> Note: I am using the router that I import like so `import { router } from "expo-router";`

Things I have tried:

- Using `useNavigation`
- Using `useRouter`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<Tabs initialRouteName="my-child" backBehavior="history"`

try adding backBehavior to "history" in your Tabs component.